# Add a CSS that enlarge the value when the mouse hovers over it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table inside an html page created by Javascript and hold number inside its cells i want to enlarge the number when the mouse hovers over it using css style.

Comment: "[Enlarge] the number..." by making the number larger on screen (increasing the font-size), or by incrementing the number (turning a '1' to a '2')?

Comment: @david-thomas well he does mention using a css style.

Comment: @Groove, I'm...not sure that was there when I posted the comment. If it was, then my apologies for a silly question.

Comment: @david-thomas meh, it's fine.  I didn't even think that it may not have been written there at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do something like:

```
table td:hover {
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

This way, you're sure to have a bigger font than what's already there.

Answer (score 2):

look into [css :hover selector](http://www.w3schools.com/css/sel_hover.asp)

this mainly works for anchor tags in most browsers, if you want to do hover for other elements you might want to use javascript

Comment: Everything but IE6 supports :hover for all elements.

Comment: @SLaks♦ yes, but that is a limitation i want the OP to know that

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example: http://jsbin.com/urube4/edit

You can either use the :hover psuedo-selector on the `td`, or on the `span` inside, depending on the effect you want.

The first table in the example will only activate the hover on the `mouseover` of the text, while the second example will activate on the `mouseover` of the table cell.

As stated, you'll have an issue here with IE6, as it only recognizes `:hover` on `a` tags and form elements such as `button` and `input`. If you want IE6, you'll need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
table td:hover {
font-size: 14px; // greater than actual size
}
```